Applying an $SO(3)$ geodesic onto a unit vector results in a circle on a sphere
Let $b \in S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a unit vector. Let $R(t)=R_0 \exp(t \Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an arbitrary skew-symmetric matrix, be a geodesic in $SO(3)$. I began graphing $b(t)=R(t)b_0$ and noticed $b(t)$ always traces a circle on the unit sphere $S^2$:

Is this true for all $SO(3)$-geodesics? Is the converse true as well: namely, given any circle on the sphere, there exists some $R_0 \in SO(3)$ and $\Omega \in skew(3)$ such that $R_0\exp(t\Omega)b_0$ traces that circle?
I believe the answer is yes, and here is why. All geodesics on $SO(3)$ are curves of constant angular velocity. A sequence of rotations of constant angular velocity means that a point is rotating about some axis. This will always form a circle. Furthermore, rotations preserve vector length, and so this circle itself will always have unit length.

Yes, both of those are true. Every geodesic is a one-parameter subgroup and these are all given by rotations about some axis.

For the converse, there is a quick geometric construction.
Consider the plane containing the circle and any vector $\omega=[\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z]^T$ normal to the plane. Pick any $b_0$ on the circle, and then set $R_0 = I$ and $\Omega = [\omega]^\wedge$ (where $[r_1]^\wedge r_2 = r_1\times r_2$ for any $r_1,r_2\in \mathbb{R}^3$).
You then have $b(t) = {\rm exp}( [\omega]^\wedge t) b_0$ as generating the desired circle.
